# My ASP.Net Application is failing to build but no error shown

Tags: asp.net, azure, msbuild, nuget, publish

I am trying to build and publish my project and all of a sudden, it will no longer build. Just a note, my computer did shut down during a publish to Azure so maybe that has something to do with it? Anyways, I am trying to just build my project, and it is no longer building but I am given no error message as to why it is not building. I tried clearing my nuget cache and I still get a failed build:

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
Running restore with 4 concurrent jobs.
Reading project file C:\Users\sagarpatel\Statum\Workspace\Full\StatumHealth\StatumHealth.csproj.
Reading project file C:\Users\sagarpatel\Statum\Workspace\Full\StatumHealth\StatumHealth.csproj.
The restore inputs for 'microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.tools-netcoreapp2.1-[2.0.2, )' have not changed. No further actions are required to complete the restore.
The restore inputs for 'StatumHealth' have not changed. No further actions are required to complete the restore.
Committing restore...
Tool assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file write. Path: C:\Users\sagarpatel\.nuget\packages\.tools\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.tools\2.0.2\netcoreapp2.1\project.assets.json
No-Op restore. The cache will not be updated. Path: C:\Users\sagarpatel\.nuget\packages\.tools\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.tools\2.0.2\netcoreapp2.1\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.tools.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 44.27 ms for C:\Users\sagarpatel\Statum\Workspace\Full\StatumHealth\StatumHealth.csproj.
Committing restore...
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\Users\sagarpatel\Statum\Workspace\Full\StatumHealth\obj\project.assets.json
No-Op restore. The cache will not be updated. Path: C:\Users\sagarpatel\Statum\Workspace\Full\StatumHealth\obj\StatumHealth.csproj.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 41.29 ms for C:\Users\sagarpatel\Statum\Workspace\Full\StatumHealth\StatumHealth.csproj.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\sagarpatel\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
1>------ Build started: Project: StatumHealth, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I am not shown any errors or incompatible packages and this is preventing me from publishing my project.

Comment: unload your project, remove the obj and bin-folders, reload the project and try again, this should rebuild the temp-files for that project and hopefully either fix your issue or at least give you more output when rebuilding

Comment: the nuget restore looks successful. you could try running `msbuild -bl` from the command line. It'll create a `msbuild.binlog` that you can open with the [msbuild loger viewer](http://msbuildlog.com). I think it's just a nicer way to view `msbuild -v diag`, so you could do that if you don't want to install the log viewer. Hopefully it gives you more info about what actually failed.

Comment: Turns out my .csproj.user file was corrupted. Fixed after I reset it. I am not sure why it got corrupt but must have been because my computer shut down during the earlier publish. Thanks for the tips though, could definitely help in the future!